# question with getting total averages grouping by month and region- Google sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, average, spreadsheet

[image]I am on working on a sheet with month, region, country number , number of CSAT, and CSAT total responses, in this case, the average would be the Number of CSAT/ CSAT Total responses and I am looking to have Average CSAT score per month by region, I was thinking of creating a new column with AVG already calculated but would there be a better way to approach the question?

Comment: pls, share a simplified copy of your spreadsheet

Comment: i attached screenshot,i originally thought of pivot table but assignment is requiring of me using formulas that evaluator can trace,i am just uncertain of which function should i use,this is all that i can come up with so far =QUERY(CSAT!A:E,"SELECT B,A, D/E",1),which only gives AVG but not the total by month/region

Comment: People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you. You can always create a sheet of dummy data that people can access and play with. By doing so, people will be more eager to help out.;

Comment: I have a simplified file but I don't have an option to attach to the question,it only lets me do links or images

Comment: copy the link in your comment!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vY3Mpu2TUQwXjZL3H8P0f6cB0rC0Yx3XF5dX91qr-OY/edit#gid=345491251 let me know if this works well

Comment: access denied, you have to share it!

Comment: sorry about that https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vY3Mpu2TUQwXjZL3H8P0f6cB0rC0Yx3XF5dX91qr-OY/edit?usp=sharing, here

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eYBQfJ_waSGLKPYEDsCe8j0nah7Fh9YJZkIzG4V5m4c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JK0h1LE6NdSlzlopBpS5ETooTLTFa_Q-CCTcfzGGY64/edit?usp=sharing for solution #2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pivot table should be more suitable.

In H1, create a pivot table.

## solution #1

In L1,

```
={"Average";arrayformula(if(K2:K>0,J2:J/K2:K,))}
```

[image]

## solution, #2

add a calculated field in your pivot table with this formula

```
=iferror('Number of CSAT ''Yes'''/'CSAT responses')
```

[image]